# Como acessar o código por trás de uma Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

Como posso acessar o código por trás de uma `stored procedure`? 
Estou usando **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**

Comment: Você quer ver o código da sua procedure que já está criada no banco?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No SQL Server Management Studio, expanda o banco onde a procedure foi criada. 
Clique em <kbd>Programmability</kbd>, depois clique em <kbd>Stored Procedures</kbd>. Dentro desse diretório do <kbd>Stored Procedures</kbd> você verá todas as procedures criadas para este seu banco. Clique com o botão direito no nome da procedure que deseja ver o código, depois selecione <kbd>Script Stored Procedure as</kbd> <kbd>-></kbd> <kbd>Modify</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Se você quiser o texto em uma célula de resultado, você pode usar essa *query*:

```
select
    [text]
from
    sys.syscomments comm
    inner join sys.procedures procs on procs.object_id = comm.id
where
    procs.[name] = 'foo'
```

Apenas troque `foo` pelo nome da sua *procedure*.

Se você quiser o texto para leitura, pode abrir uma nova *query*, apertar **CTRL+T** (isso coloca os resultados da query no SSMS em modo de texto) e executar:

```
exec sp_helptext 'foo'
```

Mais uma vez, substitua `foo` pelo nome da sua *procedure*.

Ou você pode ir em:
**Servidor -> Databases ->** sua base **-> Programmability -> Stored Procedures**

...Clicar com o bitão direito na procedure e em seguida clicar em *Modify*. Assim você pode inclusive alterar e salvar sua procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser usado o comando:

```
sp_heltptext 'nomeCompletoDaProcedure'
```

Isso faz a `Procedure` retornar como registros na parte de visualização de `table` no DB. 
Caso não queira o retorno como registros pode ser usado **Ctrl+T** antes da execução para retornar o valor como texto assim como mencionado pelo usuário [Oralista de Sistemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1658/oralista-de-sistemas) nos comentários dessa resposta.

Comment: Aperta **CTRL+T** antes de executar isso que vem como um texto só ;)